# how to have access to make a file executable?

Tags: permissions, executable

I know that you need to go in permissions but I heard that theres shoud be a option executable in access section I only see those : none , write, read , write and read. how choose the executable option??

Comment: Assuming you're using regular Ubuntu or Ubuntu Gnome, there is no box at the bottom of the Permissions tab in the file properties, right of text that says 'Execute:' ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this through a GUI, the executable option is usually a checkbox below the permissions dropdown. Alternatively, you can do this through the command line by running `chmod +x filename`, where `filename` is the name of the file that needs to have the executable bit set.

Comment: it cant find it. my file name is TechnicLauncher.jar                                           chmod +x TechnicLauncher.jar <-- this is the command that I used maybe I did some thing wrong I just started using ubuntu

Comment: @thecat: Are you in the right directory? (Use `cd` if necessary)